# calling multiple web services from ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing an ios application in swift and have nearly 20+ network calls. each network calls has a set of parameters and some of the parameters are common across service calls. Is there a way I can write a helper class to which I can pass a parameter (to identify the webserivce call) and this function form the request and send it. I am looking for something like have all the parameters in a struct, arrray or something and reuse (dynamically form the request object) based on the request type.

Comment: Best way to create Parameter class where you have all fields as property to set. More you can have diff. methods which return formatted request data  to directly pass in service.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, It is very common technique to create a separate class for service calls and each call has its own method for example,

1. create service.h and .m inherted from NSObject.
2. Define methods like `-(NSArray*)getItemsWithCategory:(NSString*)cat` ,this method is responsible to get data from server with category as parameter.
3. The method should be visible (must define in .h) so that it can be called from any other
   uiviewcontroller or class.
4. In implementation use any technique to fetchDataFromURL like `AFNetworking` or `ASIHTTP` or your custom Methods.
5. define a `protocol` and Create `delegates` for success and fail OR you can use the blocks but delegate is cleaner way.
6. Set delegate to your class that make the call and implement them in that class, like `getItemWithCategory:Success` and `Fail`.
7. Populate data in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different threads that run on background and can create a webservicehelper class to handle them all for example

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(webservice1Call) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(webservice2Call) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(webservice3Call) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

In any function call different methods

```
-(void)webservice2Call{
//WebServiceHelper can be the handler class
[WebServiceHelper loadWebService1Data];

}
```

And in loadWebService1Data class function.. send a request for the call